# Undefined Control Sequence while using \setmathdigitfont in xepersian

Tags: xetex, pdftex, xepersian

I want to use Persian numbers in the math environment in my tex document. I tried to use `\setmathdigitfont{}` as below:

```
% !TEX program=xelatex

\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[localise=on,extrafootnotefeatures,displaymathdigits=default]{xepersian} 

\settextfont{Tahoma}

\setmathdigitfont{Tahoma}
\begin{document}
فارسی
$62$
\end{document}
```

but I get the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \begin
Missing \begin{document}. \begin
Extra \fi. \begin
Undefined control sequence. \begin
Extra \fi. \begin
Font shape `TU/Tahoma(1)/m/it' undefined(Font) using `TU/Tahoma(1)/m/n' instead
Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

- the errors refer to the line with `\begin{document}`

** last two lines were warning, but I included just in case.
commenting out `\setmathdigitfont{Tahoma}` will result in no error, but the numbers are English.

using `\setmathdigitfont{Tahoma}` will compile with errors, but the resulting pdf has Persian numbers. Also, there is an extra line at the beginning of the pdf.

[image]

I'm using MiKTeX and all packages are up to date.

UPDATE: It is working in overleaf.com, the problem is definitely related to MiKTeX

Comment: Try with `\ExplSyntaxOn \cs_set_eq:NN \etex_iffontchar:D \tex_iffontchar:D \ExplSyntaxOff` before loading xepersian. (if you want to work also in overleaf, you probably need some conditional to get this code only in miktex).